# Detect if user comes back (go back event) or if can go forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this structure: Cart page > Checkout page > External Page

And I need to be able to detect in Checkout page if the user has come back (because in External Page had a problem and clicked in Go Back) or comes from Cart page.

I´ve tried with document.referrer, but it´s the same page (Cart page) if the user clicked on go back in the External Page.

If I could check if the user can go forward, would be perfect. If the user cann go forward, it´s because the user clicked Go Back in the External Page.

About history length (if comes from the External page the history length has one more page), I´ve thought about sending a post variable with history.lenght in Cart, and then check with current history.length. If the difference is 1, then comes from Cart. If 2, from External Page. The problem is sending this variables from the Cart is very difficult. Can be a solution, but if I could modify only Checkout would be perfect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I´ve solved with history.pushState simulating a new Checkout page ending with #

In Checkout I do this:

```
var a = window.location.href;

if ( a.match(/#$/)) {
    window.location.replace("Cart Page");
} else {
    history.pushState({}, "", "#");
    setTimeout(function () { jQuery("#submit_form").click(); }, 4000);
}
```

The first time the Checkout url will be the normal Checkout url. Then, with pushstate, it´s as if the user has visited Checkout url ending with #. And then is forwarded to the external page. If the user comes back, the current page is Checkout ending with #.

It´s not the most elegant solution, but it works.